# Pandas: how to insert new data from list of lists under preexisting columns?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, append

So, I have an empty `pandas` dataframe that I plan to append to multiple times, which I give columns to, with

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['Author', 'Date', 'Text', 'Length', 'Favorites', 'Retweets'])
```

Eventually, I have data in the form of a list of lists (or array of arrays, if you will), and want to add all of it to the empty dataframe under the current columns.

The data is generated like this, (I am scraping data from twitter, btw)

```
input = np.array(list(zip([tweet.source for tweet in tweets],
                         [tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets], 
                         [tweet.text for tweet in tweets],
                         [len(tweet.text) for tweet in tweets],
                         [tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets],
                         [tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets])))
```

which results in an array where each item corresponds to one tweet and all the information regarding it.

If I try `dataframe.append(pd.DataFrame(input))`, I get the following messy result,

[image]

In this situation, how can I efficiently append such data to my dataframe?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is to create data like this:

```
input = np.array([[tweet.source, tweet.created_at, tweet.text, 
                   len(tweet.text), tweet.favorite_count, tweet.retweet_count]
                   for tweet in tweets])
```

This way, you only iterate through the tweet array once to construct the matrix, which you can then feed to pandas:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(input, columns=['Author', 'Date', 'Text', 'Length', 
                                       'Favorites', 'Retweets'])
```

It's much more efficient to construct all your data in one go, and then build a pandas Dataframe around it, than to append every observation to the Dataframe.

If you're going to go with a bucketed approach, I suggest you construct a list of dataframes using the above, and then use `pd.concat`

```
df_total = pd.concat([df1, df2, ... dfn])
```

Or if you just recieved a new batch, you can try :

```
df = pd.concat([df, df_new_batch])
```

*link to the doc of [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat)*

Comment: While I do appreciate the more efficient `input` array creation example, my twitter streaming app will process a few hundred tweets at a single go, so I need to append the data to the pandas dataframe each time. How could I do that?

Comment: Sure! You can pass a list of dataframes to `pd.concat`, which will concatenate them and return a single consolidated dataframe. See my edit !

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer! Though you have given me a fully workable and good solution, does there exist a way to do essentially what `pd.concat` does except with a dataframe and such array input as mine? I'm only asking because I don't know how efficient creating new pandas dataframes for every bucked of new data is.

Comment: The thing is, to get it to work with append you need to pass it a DataFrame, which means that you need to cast your data to a dataframe anyways. One other option perhaps would be to combine the data at the numpy level, and then cast the result to pandas?